# Errors in christopher gandrud's book reproduction from github in rstudio

Tags: r, github, rstudio

I downloaded the repository of new book reproducible research with r and rstudio from github page of christopher gandrud. Even after following the instructions, I am getting following error when I run knit2pdf in bookmake.R file:

```
running: "sh"  -c "pandoc Children/FrontMatter/StylisticConventions.md -t latex -o StyleTemp.tex"
Quitting from lines 99-100 (Rep-Res-Parent.Rnw) 
Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : '"sh"' not found﻿
```

How can I resolve  this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/christophergandrud/Rep-Res-Book/issues/37), you do not have a shell program on your windows path.

The solution is to install [RTools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and make sure you check the checkbox to modify PATH when you install RTools

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did use RTools and also followed all the other steps as described in instructions. However, it gives the error that `zeligbayesian package is not available for R version 3.03` When I switch to another R version, say 3.02 then it complains about other packages.

Comment: Have you seen this issue about that exact  message? https://github.com/christophergandrud/Rep-Res-Book/issues/35

Comment: `ZeligBayesian` was just one example. I've installed that but every time I try to compile `Rep-Res-Parent.Rnw`, it says `Execution Halted` and asks about another package. I've tried manually installing other packages but even after that it doesn't compile. I am thinking to just give up for now!

Comment: Yes I had similar issues, but manually installing all the packages after a few restarts solved it. You do need to be working from c:\ right at root, with this also.